# Best way to add MANY auto layout constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout

For an app that has many UI elements, such as the piano keyboard, adding constraints to it using Interface Builder may be complicated. Adding one by one? On no, I can't do that.
So is there a better way to add so many constraints? Programmatically?

Comment: why can't do adding them one by one actually...? that part is not really clear to me.

Comment: what became of this?

Comment: @holex Take the piano keyboard as an example, it has 88 keys, and every dimension needs at least 2 constraints. So 88 keys may need hundreds of constraints. Thats a big challenge to Interface Builder.

Comment: @AdrianB E.g., a piano keyboard that has 88 keys

Comment: This post is kind of old and short on specifics, but the author did include some pseudo code to give you an idea of what he/she did. http://www.deluge.co/?q=content/making-software-piano-keyboard-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: @Papillon, I disagree, it not a big challenge to IB, and you could have set up the constraints in an hour time (at most!) for a piano keyboard with 88 keys, so that is why I don't get your question, because you spend more time looking for alternative answers than doing the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many examples out there of adding autolayout constraints programmatically. See:

[Adding Constraints Programmatically on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594369/adding-constraints-programmatically-on-ios)

or

[Swift | Adding constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically)

for example.

Comment: For complex views like a piano keyboard, I personally prefer this approach. Theoretically, I can loop over each view and add constraints programatically (or use visual format language). But I have not tried.